# How to fix Updating mongodb data from form using expressjs the ObjectId() make the error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

when I'm updating data through filtering _id and converted the _id from the form to ObjectId then the error tell me Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

```
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId;
const _ID = (id)=>{
    return new ObjectId(id);
}


route.post('/edit', (req,res)=>{
    const fullname = req.body.fullname;
    const phone = req.body.phone;
    const id = req.body._id;
    mongodb()
      .collection("Regiter")
      .updateOne(
        { _id: _ID(id)},
        { $set: { Fullname: fullname, PhoneNumber: phone } }
      )
      .then(result => {
        res.redirect("/display");
        console.log(result.modifiedCount);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}); 

I expected to update data but the out is 
Error: Argument passed in must be a single string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
    at new ObjectID 

    (C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
        at _ID (C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\util\db.js:25:12)
        at route.post (C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\route\index.js:59:16)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at next (C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
        at Function.process_params (C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
        at next (C:\Users\muraadso\Documents\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

I checked this more but I didn't get until now but I tried to use id that takes req.body._id but the query work but modifiedCount is 0 and matchedCount is 0

Comment: try `   mongodb()
      .collection("Regiter")
      .updateOne(
        { _id: id},
        { $set: { Fullname: fullname, PhoneNumber: phone } }
      )`

Comment: i tried this but i returns modifiedCount is 0 and matchedCount is 0